# Module Model not loading

Tags: zend-framework, module

My application structure:

- /application

  - /models

    - ShoppingCart.php
  - /modules

    - /orders

      - /models

        - Order.php

---

I want to create a module application so in my application.ini I put:

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.modules[] = ""

---

Basically my Application_Model_ShoppingCart for my main application needs the Orders_Model_Order to place an order:

```
class Application_Model_ShoppingCart
{
 static public $mCartId;

 function __construct()
 {
  #$this->OrderModel = new Orders_Model_Order();
  $this->SetCartId();
 }
}

class Orders_Model_Order
{
 function __construct()
 {
  $this->PP_Session = Zend_Registry::get('PP_Session');

 }
}
```

---

But I keep getting a fatal error:

Fatal error: Class 'Orders_Model_Order' not found in .. /application/models/ShoppingCart.php on line 13

I keep trying different things but it still doesnt include this module with the autoloader.  Is there something I should be doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

Add in `application.ini`:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = 'Application_'
```

or add module bootstrap:

```
// /application/modules/orders/Boostrap.php
class Orders_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

and put your `Order_Model_Order` models to:

```
/application/modules/orders/models/Order.php
```

Comment: The first solution didnt work but once I added a Orders_Bootstrap (which zf create module DOES NOT create automatically) it worked.  Thanks buddy I was totally hitting a wall on this one.

Comment: @marko This is kind of the tricky one, you have to create it manually. I always forget about it too.

Answer (score -1):

I think the class must be named:

```
class Application_Orders_Model_Order
```